# Show report for child table when master table records are clicked in Crystal Reports?

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I have a master table and a child table in SQL server. I have generated a crystal report for the master table.

I want to display the child table's records as a sub report when the user clicks the master table records in the main report. Is this possible in crystal report?

Comment: are you created a sub-report too and linked with main report and you only want clickable thing? or you want to create subreport with linking of main report on click?

Comment: i have created s sub report... i need that clicking option in crystal report..